# CSF : Block Port but ignore

Tags: csf

Is it possible to block a port (port 585) and not have it trigger an IP block ?
Customers using Apple Mail are constantly hitting port 585 (I think Mac Mail attempts to go into 'troubleshooting mode' and spams the port for each email account setup on it) and subsequently getting blocked:

eg:

```
Apr 25 13:58:41 XXX lfd[545948]: *Port Scan* detected from XXX. 13 hits in the last 142 seconds - *Blocked in csf* for 3600 secs [PS_LIMIT]
```

I dont want to adjust PS_LIMIT and I dont want to open port 585, but I dont want people getting blocked for attempting port 585. Possible? I only see an IP ignore list...